# How to order items inside array based on object property in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects:

```
[
{
Name:
likes:[]
...
}
]
```

I need to order first objects with no likes where likes is undefined, then objects which has only 1 item inside likes array then other objects which have more items inside likes array. How can be it done correctly?

Comment: Why do you have both `ecmascript-5` and `ecmascript-6` tags? it is not really related to the problem and actually contradicting..

Comment: "How can be it done correctly?" - using `array.sort()` function :-) please post what are your problems. SO is not suitable for this kind (I have no code but want solution) of problems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function sortBy(selector) {
  const cmp = (a, b) => (selector(a) - selector(b));
  return list => list.sort(cmp);
}

const data = [{ Name: "Foo", likes:[{}, {}, {}] }, { Name: "Bar", likes:[{}] }, { Name: "Baz", likes:[{}] }, { Name: "Plugh", likes:[] }];

const sortByLikes = sortBy(({ likes }) => likes.length);

console.log(sortByLikes(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var temp = [
{
Name: "abc",
likes: [1,2,3]
},
{
Name: "ac",
likes:[1]
},
{
Name: "bc",
likes:null
},
{
Name: "c",
likes:[1,2,3,4]
}
];

temp = temp.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.likes === undefined || a.likes === null)
    return -1;
  else if(b.likes === undefined || b.likes === null)
    return 1;
  else{
    return a.likes.length - b.likes.length;
  }
  });

console.log(temp);
```